# My Helis Won't display when reloaded

Tags: java, arraylist, processing, reset

I'm making a multi-player chopper clone in Processing. Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<Heli> helis = new ArrayList<Heli>();
ArrayList<Heli> permaHelis = new ArrayList<Heli>();
ArrayList<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
IntDict keys = new IntDict();
float speed = 3;
float loop = 0;
float distance = 20;
float place = 100;
int numDead;
PFont f;
void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  f = createFont("Trebuchet MS", 25);
  textFont(f);
  permaHelis.add(new Heli(place, height/2, 20, 0.1, "w", color(255, 100, 100), "Dr.Swerve"));
  //permaHelis.add(new Heli(place+150, height/2, 20, 0.1, str(UP), color(255, 255, 0), "Grebbles"));
  for (int i = 0; i<=permaHelis.size()-1;i++) {
    helis.add(permaHelis.get(i));
  }
}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  background(200);
  if (loop == distance) {
    walls.add(new Wall(width+100, random(height), random(25, 100), speed, color(0, 255, 0)));
    loop=0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i<helis.size();i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<walls.size();j++) {
      walls.get(j).iterate();
      walls.get(j).display();
      if (walls.get(j).x+walls.get(j).size<=0) {
        walls.remove(i);
      }
      if (dist(helis.get(i).x, helis.get(i).y, walls.get(j).x, walls.get(j).y)<helis.get(i).size/2+walls.get(j).size/2||helis.get(i).y<0||helis.get(i).y+helis.get(i).size>height) {
        helis.get(i).explode=true;
        helis.get(i).run = false;
      }
    }
    helis.get(i).iterate();
    helis.get(i).display();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < helis.size();i++) {
    if (helis.get(i).run==false&&helis.get(i).dead == false) {
      helis.get(i).dead = true;
      numDead++;
    }
  }
```

And here's the faulty bit.

```
  if (numDead==helis.size()) {
    fill(0);
    text("Restart? (Press R)", width/2, height/2);
    if (keyPressed&&key=='r') {
      walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
      helis = new ArrayList<Heli>();
      for (int i = 0; i<=permaHelis.size()-1;i++) {
        helis.add(permaHelis.get(i));
      }
      numDead = 0;
    }
  }
  loop++;
}
```

And a little key-checker at the bottom.

```
void keyEvent(int pressed) {
  if (key==CODED) {
    keys.set(str(keyCode), pressed);
  }
  else {
    keys.set(str(key), pressed);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  keyEvent(1);
}

void keyReleased() {
  keyEvent(0);
}
```

So when I press R to restart, the heli scores stay, unchanging, at the top of the screen, but the helis themselves don't display. Also, the walls restart fine. The array empties and new walls come in from the right of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this java? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: @hichris123 : The question is language-tagged correctly as Processing. It's Java-based, but has some differences.

Comment: although if tagged also as java, syntax highlighting would work...

Comment: There you go. Hope that's better.

Comment: Fun fact: you can put this: `<!-- language: java -->` before code snippets and it will highlight it without having to tag the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

Where you do this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i<=permaHelis.size()-1;i++) {
  helis.add(permaHelis.get(i));
}
```

You can instead use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
helis.addAll(permaHelis);
```

In this snippet, you redisplay every wall for each heli, which isn't good (because if you have ten helis, each wall is getting displayed ten times per frame!). You could have a separate loop just for the `walls` list to display it.

```
  for (int i = 0; i<helis.size();i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<walls.size();j++) {
      walls.get(j).iterate();
      walls.get(j).display();
```

I think you had a typo here. Should it be `walls.remove(j);`?

```
  if (walls.get(j).x+walls.get(j).size<=0) {
    walls.remove(i);
  }
```

Finally, on to your question. I can't say for sure without the code for the classes, but what I think is happening is this. You create your permaHeli, fine. You add it to the list of normal helis, fine, but it doesn't *copy* the object, it only adds a reference to it. So, when you do things like `helis.get(i).dead = true;`, you're actually changing the original permaHeli, too! Then, when you hit R and reset it, it's clearing the list and adding an already dead heli into it. Try putting `println(helis.get(i).dead);` in a for loop somewhere to see if this is true. If it is, all you need to do is create a new heli instead of re-using the permaHelis list (but maybe then the permaHelis aren't useful anymore).